# Grouping Multidimensional Arrays by Particular Value with nested Standard Class Objects

Tags: php, arrays, object, multidimensional-array, grouping

In a previous post there was a very helpful answer on grouping multidimensional arrays. My issue is similar with the twist that my initial array has a nested standard class object. My array looks like this:

```
Array
(
    [0] => stdClass Object
        (
            [InstallationAddress2] => LAKEWOOD, CA  90000
            [LineitemmasterDescription] => Apples
            [Workorder_id] => W008052094
        )

    [1] => stdClass Object
        (
            [InstallationAddress2] => Santa Rosa, CA  90230
            [LineitemmasterDescription] => Berries
            [Workorder_id] => W008022342
        )

    [2] => stdClass Object
        (
            [InstallationAddress2] => LAKEWOOD, CA  90000
            [LineitemmasterDescription] => Apples
            [Workorder_id] => W008052094
        )
)
```

Like the previous post I'm hoping to get something like

```
Array
(
    [1] => Array
        [0] => Array
            (
            [InstallationAddress2] => LAKEWOOD, CA  90000
            [LineitemmasterDescription] => Apples
            [Workorder_id] => W008052094
           )

        [1] => Array
          (
            [InstallationAddress2] => LAKEWOOD, CA  90000
            [LineitemmasterDescription] => Apples
            [Workorder_id] => W008052094
          )

        [2] => Array
        (
            [InstallationAddress2] => Santa Rosa, CA  90230
            [LineitemmasterDescription] => Berries
            [Workorder_id] => W008022342
        )
)
```

The thing I'm stumbling over is the standard class object which refuses to be cast into an array.

Comment: What is the previous question? Do you have to transform the objects to arrays? It is probably easier to change the code to work on objects instead of arrays.

Answer (score 0):

do (array) type cast of each of the std objects by looping through your array.

```
for($i=0;$i< count($myArray);  $i++)
    $myArray[$i] = (array)$myArray[$i];
```

Then you can apply your grouping logic.
See typecasting example :  http://codepad.org/uVuBzBm8